# Problem locating media file using Django's static function in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using Django 3.2

I am trying to integrate a blog app that has a slightly convoluted directory structure for its static assets. Here is the relevant part of the tree:

#### Blog app static assets directory structure

```
blog/static/blog/
├── css
│   ├── bona
│   │   ├── comment.css
│   │   ├── detail-page.css
│   │   ├── prism.css
│   │   ├── responsive.css
│   │   ├── styles
│   │   └── styles.css
│   ├── common-css
│   │   ├── bootstrap.css
│   │   ├── fontawesome-free
│   │   ├── ionicons.css
│   │   ├── ionicons.min.css
│   │   └── swiper.css
│   └── tinymce
│       ├── github.css
│       └── tomorrow-night-blue.css
├── font
│   ├── fontello.eot
│   ├── fontello.svg
│   ├── fontello.ttf
│   ├── fontello.woff
│   └── fontello.woff2
├── fonts
│   ├── Aileron
│   │   ├── Aileron-Black.otf
│   │   ├── Aileron-Bold.otf
│   │   ├── Aileron-Heavy.otf
│   │   ├── Aileron-Italic.otf
│   │   ├── Aileron-Light.otf
│   │   ├── Aileron-Regular.otf
│   │   ├── Aileron-SemiBold.otf
│   │   ├── Aileron-Thin.otf
│   │   ├── Aileron-UltraLight.otf
│   │   └── Gidole-Regular.ttf
│   ├── Colaborate
│   │   ├── ColabBol.otf
│   │   ├── ColabLig.otf
│   │   ├── ColabMed.otf
│   │   ├── ColabReg.otf
│   │   └── ColabThi.otf
│   ├── ionicons.eot
│   ├── ionicons.svg
│   ├── ionicons.ttf
│   ├── ionicons.woff
│   ├── linea-basic-10.eot
│   ├── linea-basic-10.svg
│   ├── linea-basic-10.ttf
│   ├── linea-basic-10.woff
│   ├── Material-Design-Iconic-Font.eot
│   ├── Material-Design-Iconic-Font.svg
│   ├── Material-Design-Iconic-Font.ttf
│   ├── Material-Design-Iconic-Font.woff
│   ├── Material-Design-Iconic-Font.woff2
│   ├── Roboto
│   │   ├── LICENSE.txt
│   │   ├── Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf
│   │   ├── Roboto-Black.ttf
│   │   ├── Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf
│   │   ├── Roboto-Bold.ttf
│   │   ├── Roboto-Italic.ttf
│   │   ├── Roboto-LightItalic.ttf
│   │   ├── Roboto-Light.ttf
│   │   ├── Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf
│   │   ├── Roboto-Medium.ttf
│   │   ├── Roboto-Regular.ttf
│   │   ├── Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf
│   │   └── Roboto-Thin.ttf
│   ├── Roboto_Condensed
│   │   ├── LICENSE.txt
│   │   ├── RobotoCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf
│   │   ├── RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf
│   │   ├── RobotoCondensed-Italic.ttf
│   │   ├── RobotoCondensed-LightItalic.ttf
│   │   ├── RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf
│   │   └── RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf
│   └── Spirequal-Light
│       └── Spirequal-Light.TTF
├── images
│   ├── authors_banner2.png
│   ├── authors_banner.png
│   ├── banner.jpeg
│   ├── blog-1-1000x600.jpg
│   ├── category-1-400x250.jpg
│   ├── category-3-400x250.jpg
│   ├── favicon.png
│   ├── logo.png
│   ├── marion-michele-330691.jpg
│   ├── media
│   │   ├── article-default.jpg
│   │   ├── banner
│   │   ├── category-default.jpg
│   │   ├── profile-pic-default.jpg
│   │   └── slider-1.jpg
│   ├── pexels-photo-370474.jpeg
│   ├── slider-1-1600x900.jpg
│   └── slider-1.jpg
└── js
    ├── blog
    │   ├── blog.js
    │   ├── highlight.pack.js
    │   └── prism.js
    ├── bootstrap
    │   └── bootstrap.bundle.min.js
    └── common-js
        ├── bootstrap.js
        ├── jquery-3.1.1.min.js
        ├── scripts.js
        ├── swiper.js
        └── tether.min.js
```

#### Snippet of template

```
<img alt="author-profile-image" src="{% static author_profile_details.profile.image.url %}" class="rounded-circle border border-dark shadow-sm">
```

The image `src` above is resolved to the path: `/static/media/profile-pic-default.jpg`

But (as can be seen from the directory path above), the correct path should be:
`static/media/blog/images/media/profile-pic-default.jpg` (I think - I haven't quite got my heard around static file deployment).

My question is - given the directory structure of the blog app's static assets, how do I use `static` to correctly locate the `profile-pic-default.jpg` asset?

Comment: `{{ static author_profile_details.profile.image.url }}`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That resolves to the same path as above - Django seems to be disregarding the namespacing of apps

Comment: "Media files" != "Static files". Static files are your websites static assets (logos, images, css, etc.). Media files are _user uploaded content_. Hence you only need to write `{{ author_profile_details.profile.image.url }}` (if you write it correctly and your media settings are correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without specifics of the model, I'm going to assume that this is an ImageField for which the app provides a static default.

In this case, the correct way to code it in a template is:

```
{% if author_profile_details.profile.image %}
<img
    alt="author-profile-image"
    src="{{ author_profile_details.profile.image.url }}"
    class="rounded-circle border border-dark shadow-sm">
>
{% else %}
<img
    alt="author-profile-image"
    src="{% static 'blog/images/media/profile-pic-default.jpg' %}"
    class="rounded-circle border border-dark shadow-sm">
>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Your reasoning seems sound ... I'm studying my code to get a clearer understanding of what is happening, before accepting your answer - if it helps fix the problem. Thanks